# Syntactic errors

Tags: c, parsing

I'm writing code for the exercise 1-24, K&R2, which asks to write a basic syntactic debugger.

I made a parser with states normal, dquote, squote etc...

So I'm wondering if a code snippet like

```
/" text "
```

is allowed in the code? Should I report this as an error? (The problem is my parser goes into comment_entry state after `/` and ignores the `"`.)

Comment: Shouldn't comments start with `/*`?

Comment: Shouldn't division have a left operand?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since a single `/` just means division it should not be interpreted as a comment. There is no division operator defined for strings, so something like `"abc"/"def"` doesn't make much sense, but it should not be a syntax error. Figuring out if this division is possible should not be done by the parser, but be left for later stages of the compilation to be decided there.

Answer (score 2):

That is syntactically valid, but not semantically. It should parse as the division operator followed by a string literal. You can't divide stuff by a string literal, so it's not legal code, overall.

Comments start with a two-character token, `/*`, and end with `*/`.

Answer (score 0):

As a standalone syntactical element this should be reported as an error.

Theoretically (as part of an expression) it would be possible to write

```
a= b /"text";   / a = b divided through address of string literal "text"
```

which is also wrong (you can't divide through a pointer).

But on the surface level would seem okay because it would syntactically decode as:  variable operator variable operator constant-expression (address of string).

The real error would probably have to be caught in a deeper state of syntactical analysis (i.e. when checking if given types are suitable for the division operator).